# ListView with two different list items

Tags: android, listview

I would like to have a listView that the first list item will have a red background and the second will have black.Is that possible?And if yes,how will i create the custom list adapter?
thanks!!

```
|Black item|


|Red item|


|Black item|

|Red item|

|Black item|
```

etc.

Comment: and if i want to use two different png for background and not two different colors??

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, you really have complete flexibility to do whatever you like at each position within the list. and when you extend `BaseAdapter` there is very little you need to do besides write your `getView` method, which is the main thing, after all.

Comment: i want in each  list item to have the same layout,but use a different image as background..how can i do this?

Comment: in getView, after you have the view you're going to use, set its image background, assuming that's something you can do programmatically (that aspect of it I'm not familiar with)

Answer (score 2):

You should Override getView in your arrayadapter. One of the parameters passed into this method is a position. So you can just do the position % 2 to determine if the row is even or odd. Depending on what you want to do you can change you can inflate two totally different layouts there.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method make it apply different style for each `position %2 == 0`. This way you can easily make those items differ from each other :)

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

here's the `getView` from my latest project's adapter. I've simplified it to highlight a couple of things: 1. that you can use whatever criteria you like to decide what kind of view will be returned, and 2. that you can use `LayoutInflater.inflate` to get any kind of view at all, whatever the case may be.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  View v;

  int n = itemList.get(position);
  if (n < 0)
  {
    v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
  }
  else if (n > 0)
  {
    v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
  }
  else
    v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout3, null);

  return v;
}
```

Comment: how do i have to initialize the itemList in my list_adapter class?